# Converting a string type column to a numeric column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

#### **Context/ Question**

Say I have a DataFrame like below where `col2` is a `string`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2': ['7.7/10','8.2/10','5.8/10','9.2/10','8.9/10'] }
```

Whats the best way to change the string values of `col2` to numeric.

E.g `7.7/10 = 0.77`

#### **Tried**

I have tried to use the `pd.to_numeric()` method however since the column values have the `/` I don't think it works

```
df.col2 = pd.to_numeric(df.col2, downcast= 'float')
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: weirdly enough ast.literal_eval is not working for me in Python 3.7 or Python 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only divisions like the in the example are involved you could do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2': ['7.7/10', '8.2/10', '5.8/10', '9.2/10', '8.9/10']})


def fun(x):
    a, b = x.split("/")
    return float(a) * (1 / float(b))


res = df["col2"].apply(fun)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0    0.77
1    0.82
2    0.58
3    0.92
4    0.89
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

As an alternative, if more complex operations are involved you could use [`numexpr.evaluate`](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/projects/NumExpr3/en/latest/api.html#numexpr.evaluate):

```
import numexpr
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2': ['7.7/10', '8.2/10', '5.8/10', '9.2/10', '8.9/10']})
res = df["col2"].apply(numexpr.evaluate)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0    0.77
1    0.82
2    0.58
3    0.92
4    0.89
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

Note that `numexpr` is a third-party module that needs to be installed. Finally, as a last resource, if you trust the source of the data, you could use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2': ['7.7/10', '8.2/10', '5.8/10', '9.2/10', '8.9/10']})
res = df["col2"].apply(eval)
print(res)
```

A safer alternative to the evil eval, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/4001592).